# Force download corrupts ZIP file

Tags: php

I wrote a very simple web form that allows my user to view text files from within their Internet browser.

I implemented a feature whereby the text files returned by the search are compressed into a ZIP. Here's my code

```
        function getFiles() {
         $result = null;
         $ZIPresult = null;
         if (empty($_POST['DBRIDs'])) { return null; }
         $mydir = MYDIR; 
         $dir = opendir($mydir);
         $DBRIDs = $_POST['DBRIDs'];
         $getfilename = mysql_query("select filename from search_table where rid in (" . $DBRIDs . ")") or die(mysql_error());
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfilename)) {
         $filename = $row['filename'];
         $result .= '<tr><td><a href="' . basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename . '" target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></td></tr>';
         $ZIPresult .= basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename;
        } 
        if ($result) {
        $result = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Search Results.</td></tr> $result</table>";
       shell_exec("zip -9 SearchResult.zip ". $ZIPresult ." > /dev/null ");

$fileName = 'SearchResult.zip';
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header("Content-length: " . filesize($fileName));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
readfile($fileName); 
        } return $result;
        }
```

It works great If I download the ZIP file from the server using FTP (for example) but I force the download from the page header, the ZIP is corrupted.

What am I missing? Thanks for your input.

**PS: The new ZipArchive() library/class is not available on our production environment so I chose to use the Unix utility ZIP instead.**

Comment: Have you used a text/hex editor to look at the .zip file to see why it's corrupted? Perhaps there's some PHP warnings that get embedded in the downloaded data. Do the file sizes match on the server and on the client?

Comment: @MarcB: No to your first question. Yes, file sizes match on the both server and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an encoding problem. Try encoding it with Base64.

Header:
`header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');`

Then, to throw the file base64_encoded()ed to the browser, try the following:

```
ob_start(); // Starts output buffering.
readfile($fileName); // "Outputs" the file.
$content = ob_get_clean(); // Grabs the output and assigns it to a variable.
print base64_encode($content); // Encodes and prints the content to the browser.
```

Note that simply `base64_encode(readfile($fileName))` won't work because readfile() outputs data but doesn't return it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you!! The encoding was the issue. Accepted and voted up.